# Place Logo Properly in BeamerPlace Logo Properly in Beamer with pgf

Tags: beamer

I try to custom my beamer presentation and I want place my logo in left in the frametitle.

The best solution i found is [here](http://jhshi.me/2013/12/02/place-logo-properly-in-beamer/). Others solution are very complicate for a simple task (more and more code line for just deplace the logo [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170241/logo-position-of-title-page) [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27906/positioning-logo-in-the-front-page-as-well-as-slides)).

The command \pgfbox delete my content:

[image]

So i use this command: `\logo{\pgfputat{\pgfxy(9.45,1.5)}{\includegraphics[width=1.7cm]{logo.png}}}` and the problem is the "zindex" logo is lower than the frametitle so I've this rendering:

[image]