# Graphics Formatting for Presentation

Tags: graphics, formatting, presentations

I am trying to create a university presentation and am having a bit of trouble formatting the University logo correctly on the first slide.

I am using the popular Overleaf template found [here](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/presentation-template/ycwnkvzxyzwv).

My immediate code for this slide is:

```
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{figure}[htp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=4cm]{COBlogo.jpg}
\end{figure}

\title[Short title]{Main Topic } % The short title appears at the bottom of every slide, the full title is only on the title page

\author{John Smith} % Your name
\institute[UCLA] % Your institution as it will appear on the bottom of every slide, may be shorthand to save space
{
University of California \\ % Your institution for the title page
\medskip
\textit{john@smith.com} % Your email address
}
\date{\today} % Date, can be changed to a custom date

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage % Print the title page as the first slide
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Overview} % Table of contents slide, comment this block out to remove it
\tableofcontents % Throughout your presentation, if you choose to use \section{} and \subsection{} commands, these will automatically be printed on this slide as an overview of your presentation
\end{frame}
```

However, when I add the figure code in as shown at the top of the code, I get this result:

[image]

I would like the university logo to be centered and below the "Main topic" box. I have tried copying and pasting the add figure code to other positions (ie further down the code after the Name etc.) but have had no luck.

Any ideas on the code I need to use to format this correctly? Any ideas, advice, or links to examples would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: please have a look at the answer below

Answer (score -1):

I do not have the logo so used a dummy blank --remove the first line of the code in actuals when replacing

The beamer template for title page can be changed with the help of `\setbeamertemplate` as described here -- [Logo position of title page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170241/logo-position-of-title-page)

The line

```
\centering{\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic}\par\vskip1em
```

specifically places the logo below the title -- the separation can be varied with the help of the `\vskip2em` command

and the result

[image]

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx} % remove this line in your document
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\title{A title}
\author{Me}
\institute{My Institute}
\titlegraphic{\raggedright\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=1cm]{COBlogo.jpg}} % 
 adjust width/ height 

\setbeamertemplate{title page}
{
  \vbox{}
  \begingroup
    \centering
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{title}
      \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par%
      \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
        \vskip0.25em%
        {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}%
      \fi%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
\vskip2em%<-------------------------spacing
    \centering{\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic}\par\vskip1em
    \vskip1em\par
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{author}
      \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{institute}
      \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{date}
      \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  \endgroup
  \vfill
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Some Text
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. Unfortunately I am very new to latex, so I did not follow this answer.

Comment: @Ethan  you can edit the contents or copy it from overleaf at -- https://www.overleaf.com/6859789142zrbrjnwttsfm
--- if you give me the email can send it across from overleaf as a share